# Move folder in Spoon PDI

Tags: xml, pentaho, kettle, spoon, pdi

I'm trying to move a folder that I'm handling in Spoon PDI. The task is to extract an XML file from the folder, and upload the contents of this to a database. I've got this working successfully. Now, I need to move the entire folder to an archive. I've got a problem with this however. When I'm trying to move the folder, only the XML file is moved and the folder remains.

I need to move the ENTIRE folder, not just the contents (XML file) of the folder.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, you can try

`Zipping the folder once you are done reading with the XML file >> Move the Zipped file to the destination >> Delete the remains.`

This is just an alternate way. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I looked into doing this in the move files step in a job and am seeing what you have. So strange that move to folder seems to be grayed out no matter what you pick. Since you already have the file name in the transformation you could move the file and folder using the process files step there. Maybe that would work

Comment: You could also use shell script commands like mv if you want to keep it at the job level

Comment: I've got this resolved with more of a work-around (would prefer if I could come back to this and get it working, although for now it's good enough). First, I use the copy files step, which moves everything into the correct designated folder as expected. I'm then using a Delete folder step just to wipe the entire source folder. In the Spoon Job that puts the XML files there for backup, I then re-create this folder before putting the backups there. It works, and is good enough for now. However, I'm not one for work-around solutions.

Comment: Glad you got it to sort of work. Maybe you could try this also. In the move files step put the 2nd parent up folder of the file you want to copy and used the wild card expression to navigate to the file you wanted. It seems like it would work and shows that it is trying to bring the folder(testa) with the file to destination folder(testb) but I get... : There was an error moving file [file:///C:/test/testa/doc.txt] to [file:///C:/test/testb/testa/doc.txt] : [Could not rename "file:///C:/test/testa/doc.txt" to "file:///C:/test/testb/testa/doc.txt".] Maybe it is just my version of Pentaho.

Comment: I had that error too when trying this solution. I think what's happening is when it's moving, it's trying to name the folder: file:///C:/test/testa/doc.txt" to "file:///C:/test/testb/testa/doc.txt.

This is wrong as you can't have "///" in a directory. It's just what I think, I didn't really get a chance to play around with it. But it looks like it's an error in Spoon itself trying to write the Directory like that.